# Getting "None" when running if loop that appends list

Tags: python, if-statement, probability

I am trying to write a code that gives the probability of two people having the same birthday using a random seed. When I run an if statement I get the return "None". In my if statement I append a list with the random seed using: `list1.append(random.seed(2020))`

Two questions:

- Is the random.seed able to be called like that inside an if loop
- Is there a way to limit the number range of what the random seed can produce since it needs to be a number between 1 and 365?

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL5Fa.jpg)

Comment: `seed` should be called once. It affects all further calls to the `random` library's functions. It does not return a value. Read more about how seeds work here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

Comment: seed() *can* be called in a loop, but is not usually done.

Comment: Please don't post images or links to images of code. Simply copy-paste it in your question and format it accordingly. BTW, `if` is not a loop...

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this inside your loop:

```
    list1.append(random.randint(1,365))
```

I’m guessing that seed() returns None.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a random number, you should use the randint method instead of the seed.

So, your code should be

```
 list1.append(random.randint(1,365))
```

Instead of

```
 list1.append(random.seed(2020))
```